# Taylor expansion of $x/W(x)$

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion, lambert-w, polylogarithm

> For $x>e$, express $x/W(x)$ with respect to $\ln(x)$ and $\ln \ln(x)$, where $W(\cdot)$ is the Lambert-W function.

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions), we can find the expression of $W(x)$ with respect to  $\ln(x)$ and $\ln \ln(x)$. I am not sure how they got that. I need to do this for $x/W(x)$.

Comment: Google does not give any related result to the word ‘polylog expression’.

Comment: Where does this task come from?

Answer (score 2):

Di you mean  "productlog"? The word "polylog" may be an abbreviated form of
[polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). 
In the Wolfram Language
 $\,\texttt{ProductLog[x]}\,$ is used for $\,W(x).\,$ We have
 $$\, W(x) = x - x^2 + 3x^3/2! - 16x^4/3! + 125x^5/4! + O(x^5) \,$$ and
 $$\, x/W(x) = 1 + x - x^2/2 + 2x^3/3 - 9x^4/8 + 32x^5/15 + O(x^6). \,$$
These power series have a limited radius of convergence. The Wikipedia series using $\, L_1:=\ln(x)\,$ and $\, L_2:=\ln\ln(x) \,$ are asymptotic but you can just substitute that series into $\, x/W(x). \,$ Explicity,
 $$\, x/W(x) = x\left(1/L_1 + L_2/L_1^2 + L_2(L_2-1)/L_1^3 + L_2(2 -5L_2 +L_2^2)/(2L_1^4) + O(1/L_1^5)\right). $$

Comment: Would you have an idea for the expansion of $\sqrt{\frac x{W(x)}}$ for large values of $x$ ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I would try square rooting my $\,x/W(x)\,$ expansion to get $\,\sqrt{x/L_1}(1 + L_2/(2L_1) + L_2(3L_2-4)/(8L_1^2)+\dots).$

Comment: Thanks ! I never feel comfortable with log's raised to fractional powers. Cheers :-)